# Google Maps returning wrong boundary coordinates

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, openstreetmap

If you look up "Mississauga" on Google Maps, it returns boundaries that look like this:

[image: Google Maps Bounds]

What I need are the Southwest and Northeast coordinates of the boundary (the red square in the picture above).

However, when I use the [Google Maps API](https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=Mississauga), it returns the following bounds:

```
    "bounds": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 43.737351,
        "lng": -79.17856599999999
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 43.4173019,
        "lng": -79.8101295
      }
    },
```

But when you plug these values into a map plotter, it gives the following area:

[image: Google API bounds]

Which is ridiculously wrong as it includes almost all of Toronto, rather than just Mississauga.

How can I get the *proper* boundary coordinates of a city? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a KMZ or KML file that contains the bounds of Mississauga.  A search for Mississauga KMZ, returned [this link](http://opendata.peelregion.ca/data-categories/regional-geography/municipal-boundaries.aspx)

I edited the [file to just contain Mississauga](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/Mississauga.kmz)

[Displayed on KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/Mississauga.kmz)

[image: Screenshot of map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/Mississauga.kmz",
    map: map
  })

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to display the bounds, I simply want to get the SW and NE coordinates of the city so that I can zoom to an appropriate level when initializing the map.

Comment: If you want to do it in general, then you need to report the error to Google.  If the bounds of the KML data in my answer work, you can use those.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the Geocoder nor what you're doing.

This bounds from geocoder is covering just enough.

```
"bounds": {
  "northeast": {
    "lat": 43.737351,
    "lng": -79.17856599999999
  },
  "southwest": {
    "lat": 43.4173019,
    "lng": -79.8101295
  }
},
```

It may seem like the Geocoder extended Mississauga's bounds to Toronto, but that is not the real case.

The bounds are extending up to the part of Lake Ontario that belongs to Mississauga, right below the lake part that belongs to Toronto.

The Mississauga area looks something like this when the lake area is also highlighted: http://jsbin.com/xoxevaw/edit?output (Note: The coordinates used for the poly lines which highlights the lake are just approximate)